# Squid throws error, The requested URL could not be retrieved

Tags: domain-name-system, http, squid

Sometimes I am getting the following error

The requested URL could not be retrieved

While trying to retrieve the URL: http://groups.google.com/

The following error was encountered:

```
Unable to determine IP address from host name for groups.google.com
```

The dnsserver returned:

```
Refused: The name server refuses to perform the specified operation.
```

This means that:

The cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL. 
 Check if the address is correct.

Your cache administrator is root.

What could be the reason for the above error ?

Regards

Supratik

Answer (score 2):

you can add this setting in squid.conf (look for it)

dns_nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

Comments from squid.conf

```
#  TAG: dns_nameservers
#   Use this if you want to specify a list of DNS name servers
#   (IP addresses) to use instead of those given in your
#   /etc/resolv.conf file.
#
#   Example: dns_nameservers 10.0.0.1 192.172.0.4
#
#Default:
# none
```

8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 are Google public dns
208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220 OpenDNS

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive DNS servers (those defined in `/etc/resolv.conf` on your proxy server if it is a Linux machine) are refusing the query.

Do you control those DNS servers?  If so perhaps your proxy server isn't allowed to do recursive lookups, but if another machine is and does the lookup for groups.google.com, then it will be in the cache of your DNS server and returned the next time your proxy asks for it.  When that cache entry expires, your proxy is then refused the query again.

What would be helpful here is running this command on your proxy server for each nameserver listed in `/etc/resolv.conf` (again assuming your proxy server is running Linux) and editing your question to include the output.

```
dig @ip.of.dns.server groups.google.com A
```